# Error - global name 'SOL_SOCKET is not defined

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a basic instant message program that uses a p2p (peer-to-peer) connection so it will not need a server. I am pretty sure nothing is wrong, but every time I run the client program I have created, I get this error:
    s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    NameError: global name 'SOL_SOCKET' is not defined
Here is the program:

```
import socket

def Receiver():

    # Create socket that supports IPv4, TCP Protocol
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print "Socket created."
    # Requests for IP of host (DNS)
    dns = "localhost"
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 25395
    try:

        s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    except socket.error as serror:
        print "socket error"
    s.bind((HOST, PORT)) # Listens on all interfaces...
    print 'Listening on port 25565'
    s.listen(True) # Listen on the newly created socket... 
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected in port 25565'
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print data
    s.close()
def Sender():

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    dns = "localhost"
    HOST = socket.gethostbyname(dns)
    port = 25565    
    # Connect to server
    s.connect((host,port))

    print "Socket connected to " + dns + " on IP " + host

    # Assign message to be sent to server to a variable
    message = raw_input("Message to be sent to server: ")

    #Send the actual message to server
    s.sendall(message)
    print "Message sent successfully"
    s.close()


input = raw_input('S is send, R is receive: ')
if input == 's':
    Sender()
if input == 'r':
    Receiver()
```

I have tried removing s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) but it tells me that I cannot use 2 sockets on the same port when there isn't 2 sockets using the same port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code:

```
 s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

do like:

```
 s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  #            ^^^^ added         ^^^
```

because you imported just `socket`, check following code pieces:

```
>>> import socket
>>> SOL_SOCKET
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'SOL_SOCKET' is not defined
>>> socket.SOL_SOCKET
1
```

Comment: Now it gives me this error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Comment: Don't worry I fixed it.

Comment: @spider93286 how did you fixed it? I would like to know.